# KeyError warning from pandas dataframe inside plotly dash chained callback

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash, keyerror

I got multiple dropdowns that I'd like to populate depending on what the user chooses in the previous dropdown. I populate the first dropdown with:

```
schools_requests = requests.get("http://ipwhatever:portwhatever/list_all_schools")
schools_data = schools_requests.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(schools_data)
nome = df['nome'].tolist()
```

It gives me the names of the schools I got listed. I then send it (nome) to the first dropdown like this:

```
html.Label('Escola'),
        dcc.Dropdown(
        options = nome,
        id = "escola",
    )
```

The first callback works fine and it's the one down below:

```
@callback(
    Output('id_school', 'children'),
    Input('escola','value')
)
def find_id_school(school_name):
    all_schools = requests.get(
        "http://ipwhatever:portwhatever/list_all_schools")
    all_schools_data = all_schools.json()    
    for element in all_schools_data:
        if school_name == element['nome']:
            id_school = element['id_escola']
            return id_school
```

It basically searches for the corresponding school id given the name of the school the user chose in the first dropdown and stores this id in a hidden `html.Div`.

Now comes the second callback, where I use pandas and don't understand why it's different from the first time.

```
@callback(
    Output('ano', 'options'),
    Input('id_school', 'children')
)
def render_grade_from_school(chosen_id):
    grade = requests.get(
        "http://ipwhatever:portwhatever/grade?school_id="+str(chosen_id))
    grade_data = grade.json()
    indices = list(range(0,len(grade_data)))
    df = pd.DataFrame(grade_data, index=indices)
    ano = df['serie'].tolist()
    return ano
```

So it takes the school id, requests the grades from another endpoint and basically does the same thing as the first time I used pandas in the code.

The only difference is the index argument. It started complaining about the lack of index. So I check the length of the list of jsons, generate a list of indices like [0,1,2,...] and passes it as argument to dataframe. So it stopped complaining about it.

But now...I get a `KeyError: 'serie'`. The warning highlights this: `return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)` as the source, I don't know. Still, the dropdown 'ano' (grade) correctly updates and shows it in the dropdown. But the warning never goes away.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the data? Clearly, there is no column named `serie` at the time it executes that line.

Comment: Inserting a try except from the second callback actually worked. What I think happened is that the second callback requested information that depended on the results of the first callback, which were not chosen yet. So it only indicated an error when you loaded the page. With the try except that warning when you first load the page went away.